# New version of node.js doesn't show up after installing on Xenial

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, ubuntu-16.04, upgrade

I seem to have installed a high version of node but it doesn't show up with `node -v` command.

```
(base) $ sudo n 10.11.0

  installing : node-v10.11.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.11.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.11.0/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
   installed : v10.11.0 (with npm 6.4.1)

(base) $ node -v
v8.0.0

(base) $ ng
You are running version v8.0.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.

Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output shown in the question's body, I noticed
`sudo n 10.11.0` has installed new version of `node` in *this* directory: `/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.11.0`.

That path needs to be added to `$PATH` for bash to find it as follows:

`PATH=/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.11.0/bin/:$PATH`

Add the following export statement to the `~/.bashrc`:

`export PATH=/usr/local/n/versions/node/10.11.0/bin/:$PATH`

You need to start a new terminal to see the effects of modifying `~/.bashrc`